# Update and Remove SubList Item by Query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to use MongoDB Atlas Triggers and Functions to update subcollections. So I have a Collection called Statements something like this:

```
Statements = [
    {
        "_id": UUID('89dc6598-99d3-457f-b52d-22c1a01682a2'),
        CustomerId: UUID('d920c2af-db60-489b-96d0-9049c68c8ce2'),
        ExerciseYear: 2021,
        Balance: 5000
    },
    {
        "_id": UUID('c41158c3-49f7-4bfc-a12f-6f46f1dadd9e'),
        CustomerId: UUID('d920c2af-db60-489b-96d0-9049c68c8ce2'),
        ExerciseYear: 2022,
        Balance:2400
    },
    {
        "_id": UUID('110de46d-5f0a-43e9-88d6-30ec094e4b4b'),
        CustomerId: UUID('d920c2af-db60-489b-96d0-9049c68c8ce2'),
        ExerciseYear: 2023,
        Balance: 5185
    }    
]
```

And I have a Customers collection, like this:

```
Customers = [
    {
        _id: UUID('d920c2af-db60-489b-96d0-9049c68c8ce2'),
        Name: "Ivan Casanova",
        Statements : [
            {
                CalendarYear: {
                    _id: 2021
                },
                Balance: 5000
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

When the Statements collection is updated/changed, I need to find the Customer in the Customers collection and update(Create, Update or Remove) the related subCollection item.

So I wonder what would a reliable way of setting the functions, to garantee no duplicates or that the right record is found and dealt with properly.

Creation

```
//I call this way: 
context.functions.execute("ListItemCreated", statementObject, "Statements", CustomerId, fullDocument["ExerciseYear"], "CalendarYear._id", "customers");
```

```
exports = async function(object, listName, docId, queryId, queryIdKey, collection){
  const mongodb = context.services.get("Cluster0");
  const mongoDBCollection = mongodb.db("conf").collection(collection);
  const logTriggersCollection = mongodb.db("conf").collection("logs.triggers");
  
  var obj = {};
  var key = listName;
  obj[key] = object;
  
  var query = {};
  query._id = docId;
  var queryKey = listName + "." + queryIdKey;
  query[queryKey] = queryId;  
  
  mongoDBCollection.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: docId },
    { $addToSet:  obj}
  );
 
};
```

Update

```
I call this way:
context.functions.execute("ListItemUpdated", statementObject, "Statements", CustomerId, fullDocument["ExerciseYear"], "CalendarYear._id", "customers");
```

```
exports = async function(object, listName, docId, queryId, queryIdKey, collection){
  const mongodb = context.services.get("Cluster0");
  const mongoDBCollection = mongodb.db("conf").collection(collection);
  const logTriggersCollection = mongodb.db("conf").collection("logs.triggers");

  var obj = {};
  var key = listName + ".$";
  obj[key] = object;
    
  var query = {};
  query._id = docId;
  var queryKey = listName + "." + queryIdKey;
  query[queryKey] = queryId;

  mongoDBCollection.findOneAndUpdate(query, {$set : obj});
  
};
```

Removal ( its no even working)

```
//I call this way:
context.functions.execute("ListItemRemoved", newIrpfStatement, "IrpfPeriodInformations", CustomerId, fullDocument["ExerciseYear"],  "CalendarYear._id", "customers");
```

```
exports = async function(object, listName, docId, queryId, queryIdKey, collection){
  const mongodb = context.services.get("Cluster0");
  const mongoDBCollection = mongodb.db("conf").collection(collection);

  var obj = {};
  var key = listName + ".$";
  obj[key] = object;
    
  var query = {};
  query._id = docId;
  var queryKey = listName + "." + queryIdKey;
  query[queryKey] = queryId;

  mongoDBCollection.findOneAndUpdate(query, {$pull : obj});
 
};
```

Anyone could point me in the right direction?
I am reading that findAndModify is better for multiple operations, but I tried and did not manage to work.

**Ps.: There are other subcollections needed to update, but the have the original _id from the origin collections, but some of then have only the CalendarYar._id, so I need to make the query based on this CalendarYear.**

**Ps2.: Notice change from ExerciseYear to CalendarYear._id in the Customers collection.**